Svelte 5 library for syncing any remote states
I have an existing Svelte 4 app which uses stores.
I would like to rewrite it to Svelte 5 and make reusable function or class which synchronizes reactive states (runes) for any app states. $states should be synchronized both ways (like bind in components) some only one way (send) like $derived.
Backend can be MQTT or WebSocket and it is synchronizing states between clients.
There can be tens of variables to sync and I don't want to write 20 $effects for sending and 20 ifs for subscriptions.
MQTT Component with $bindable props would maybe work, but as I understand components should be mounted to DOM, and syncing variables to MQTT has nothing to do with DOM.

Create state object and dynamically set getters and setters:
lib/mqtt.svelte.js:
function mqttState(initObject) {
  const state = $state(initObject);
  let send = () => { };

  function mount(opts) {
    const options = {
      mqtt: 'wss://test.mosquitto.org:8081',
      space: 'demo',
      password: 'demo',
      path: undefined,
    };
    Object.assign(options, opts);
    options.path = options.path || `${options.space}/${options.password}`;
    if (!options.path.endsWith('/')) options.path += '/';
    const client = mqtt.connect(options.mqtt);
    client.subscribe(options.path + '+');
    client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
      if (topic.startsWith(options.path)) {
        const key = topic.slice(options.path.length);
        state[key] = JSON.parse(message.toString());
      }
    })
    send = function send(key, value) {
      client.publish(options.path + key, JSON.stringify(value), { retain: true });
    }
  }

  const o = { mount };
  /* Build getters/setters */
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(initObject)) {
    Object.defineProperty(o, key, {
      enumerable: true,
      get() {
        return state[key];
      },
      set(v) {
        state[key] = v;
        send(key, v);
      },
    })
  }
  return o;
}

Then use it in your app.
app.svelte:
import { onMount } from "svelte";
import { page } from "$app/stores";
import { mqttState } from '$lib/mqtt.svelte.js'

const state = mqttState({
  show: false,
  number: '',
  text: '',
})
  
$effect(()=>{state.text = computes(state.show, state.number)});
$effect(()=>{state.number = compute2()});

onMount(() => {
  s.mount({
    space: 'myspace',
    password: $page.url.hash.slice(1) || 'demo',
    ...Object.fromEntries($page.url.searchParams)
  });
})

<input type="checkbox" bind:checked={state.show} />
<span>{state.number}. {state.text}</span>

